# Delete first column of a numpy array

Tags: python

I have the following `np.array()`:

```
[[55.3  1.   2.   2.   2.   2. ]
 [55.5  1.   2.   0.   2.   2. ]
 [54.9  2.   2.   2.   2.   2. ]
 [47.9  2.   2.   2.   0.   0. ]
 [57.   1.   2.   2.   0.   2. ]
 [56.6  1.   2.   2.   2.   2. ]
 [54.7  1.   2.   2.   2.   nan]
 [51.4  2.   2.   2.   2.   2. ]
 [55.3  2.   2.   2.   2.   nan]]
```

And I would Like to get the following one :

```
[[1.   2.   2.   2.   2. ]
 [1.   2.   0.   2.   2. ]
 [2.   2.   2.   2.   2. ]
 [2.   2.   2.   0.   0. ]
 [1.   2.   2.   0.   2. ]
 [1.   2.   2.   2.   2. ]
 [1.   2.   2.   2.   nan]
 [2.   2.   2.   2.   2. ]
 [2.   2.   2.   2.   nan]]
```

I did try :

```
MyArray[1:]#But this delete the first line

np.delete(MyArray, 0, 1) #Where I don't understand the output
[[ 2.  2.  2.  2.  2.]
 [ 1.  2.  2.  2.  2.]
 [ 1.  2.  0.  2.  2.]
 [ 2.  2.  2.  2.  2.]
 [ 2.  2.  2.  0.  0.]
 [ 1.  2.  2.  0.  2.]
 [ 1.  2.  2.  2.  2.]
 [ 1.  2.  2.  2. nan]
 [ 2.  2.  2.  2.  2.]
 [ 2.  2.  2.  2. nan]]
```

Comment: Since you want to remove a column, try `MyArray[:,1:]`

Comment: please enter array variable in python, to copy on IDE and test

Comment: Why aren't there commas in the array ? 'Cause I can't test it without them

Comment: @StijnB: There are no commas, because it is the way numpy arrays are printed. But you are right on one point this questions lacks a true [mre].

Comment: @SergeBallesta Was editing My post, Hope its better like that

Comment: The problem here is that on any true numpy array I could build *by hand*, both `MyArray[:, 1:]` and `np.delete[MyArray, 0, 1]` give the expected result...

Comment: @SergeBallesta Solved my issue doing : `arr=np.delete(arr,[0],1)` But I have a weird issue and will open an other post

Comment: @SergeBallesta Please have a look [to the issue : arrays data being changed between 2print](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71350555/11167163)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You made a bit of a mistake using np.delete,
The np.delete arguments are array,list of indexes to be deleted, axis. By using the below snippet you get the output you want.
arr=np.delete(arr,[0],1)
The problem you created was, you passed integer instead of a list, which is why it isn't giving correct output.

Comment: Please have a look [to the issue : arrays data being changed between 2print](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71350555/11167163)

Answer (score 2):

You could try: `new_array = [i[1:] for i in MyArray]`

Comment: Well this will give a Python array of numpy arrays... Not wrong but probably not what is expected here.

Answer (score 0):

Try `MyArray[:,1:]`
I think you can get rid of column 0 with this

Comment: Same issue than with `np.delete(MyArray, 0, 1)`

Answer (score 0):

It should be straight forward with

```py
new_array = MyArray[:, 1:]
```

See [this link](https://www.w3schools.com/python/numpy/numpy_array_slicing.asp#:%7E:text=Try%20it%20Yourself%20%C2%BB-,Slicing%202%2DD%20Arrays,-Example) for explanation and examples.
Or [this link](https://www.kite.com/python/answers/how-to-slice-a-2d-numpy-array-in-python#:%7E:text=array%5Brow_start%3Arow_end%2C%20column_st)